# What is wrong - import hvplot.pandas

Tags: viewer, hvplot

```
import hvplot.pandas
import hvplot.pandas
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d0834c846347> in <module>
----> 1 import hvplot.pandas

~\anaconda3\envs\PythonData\lib\site-packages\hvplot\__init__.py in <module>
     70 from .converter import HoloViewsConverter
     71 from .interactive import Interactive
---> 72 from .ui import explorer  # noqa
     73 from .utilities import hvplot_extension, output, save, show # noqa
     74 from .plotting import (hvPlot, hvPlotTabular,  # noqa

~\anaconda3\envs\PythonData\lib\site-packages\hvplot\ui.py in <module>
      7 from holoviews.element import tile_sources
      8 from holoviews.plotting.util import list_cmaps
----> 9 from panel.viewable import Viewer
     10 
     11 from .converter import HoloViewsConverter as _hvConverter

ImportError: cannot import name 'Viewer'
```

1. Uninstalled hvplot
2. uninstalled holoview
3. reinstalled - reboot - rerun same error
4. version hvplot0.8.1
5. version holoview 1.14.9
6. install and uninstalls successfull everytime

Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the version of Panel you got installed is one that is pretty old. If you still encounter this issue you should try forcing a recent Panel version with `pip/conda install hvplot panel>=0.14`.